# How do I use AutoHotKey to switch Slomo modes in Ark/Conan Exiles?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved, autohotkey, conan-exiles

Conan Exiles and Ark use the same engine. You press insert, you type "slomo 3", you press enter, and the game runs wayyy faster.

I'm trying to get an AHK script working where when I press F1, F2 and F3 it changes between slomo 1.2, 2, 3.

So far with this I haven't had any luck:

```
f1::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, {slomo 1.2}
    Send {Enter}
}
return

f3::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, {slomo 3}
    Send {Enter}
}
return
```

What's wrong here?

Edit: Got it working

```
f1::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, slomo 1.2
    Send {Enter}
    sleep, 50
}
return

f2::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, slomo 1.5
    Send {Enter}
    sleep, 50
}
return

f3::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, slomo 3
    Send {Enter}
    sleep, 50
}
return

f4::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, slomo 3333
    Send {Enter}
    sleep, 50
}
return

f5::
{
    Send {Insert}
    SendInput, god
    Send {Enter}
    sleep, 50
}
return
```

Comment: I kinda feel like this question is off-topic, because it's about scripting AHK, not about a game. Regardless, have you tried putting delay/sleep between commands? When you press f1 or f3, all those commands are sent instantly and the "slomo 1.2" and "Enter" is sent before the game even has processed the Insert command.

Comment: You might also want to test some simpler commands with AHK, to see if Ark/Conan blocks AHK, as many multiplayer games do, because it's possible to make bots with AHK

Comment: AHK works just fine in ARK and Conan Exiles. It's just these comands that don't so far. Something's wrong here. MAybe the delay, Ima test.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it worked the way you did it, I kinda expected you would have to put a small delay between each input, but if it works, it works :)